# SVProgressHUD displays in background for Modal View

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, svprogresshud

I have an `UIViewController` from which I am presenting a modal view.

```
[self presentViewController:modal animated:YES completion:nil];
```

It has two `UIBarButtonItems` (named **Cancel** and **Save**). I am performing some action on **Save** button tap. I am displaying `SVProgressHUD` Indicator on `-saveButtonTapped` method.

```
- (IBAction)saveButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Modal Save Pressed.");
    [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Loading..."];
    // Some other code...
}
```

The problem is that the indicator is not displaying in front of my `ModalView`. It starts animating but behind the `ModalView`, not in front.

---

**What is happening :**

> UIViewController ===> SVProgressHUD ===> ModalView

**What I want :**

> UIViewController ===> ModalView ===> SVProgressHUD

---

I [searched](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD/issues) but didn't find any solution for that.

Why this is happening and how to solve this issue ?

Comment: can you give some images how it's representation

Comment: @iDev : I can't but I have added the code if it can help you.

Comment: can you provide some screenshots or some additional codes inside your modalcontroller.

Comment: @Bordz : I don't think that requires at all. The code that I used is only of one line that I already mentioned in my Question.

Comment: Just some more questions: How is your modal view presented (which type of presentation)? The code added is in the ModalView, correct? does the `saveButtonPressed` dismiss your view as well? Might be related to `previousKeyWindow` not set to your modal view.

Comment: @PaulPeelen : 1) `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`, 2) Yes, 3) No

Comment: Did you try showing the HUD at any other time? Like in the view did load of your modal view?

Comment: @MarcMosby : yeah.. I tried in viewDidLoad. But the same result, not showing in foreground.

Comment: Did you try using segues instead of pushing manually? In my apps I have very similar scenarios and they all work, but I use storyboard.

Comment: @Vin try debugging on line 448-457 in SVProgressHUD.m. For debugging purposes you could make sure those lines are run when pressing the button in the modalView. The problem seems to be that the `overlay` is not being set to the `modalView`. I believe this was use previously using `previousKeyWindow`.

Comment: @PaulPeelen: I debugged and found that those lines are running perfectly.

Comment: @MarcMosby: No, I have not tried with segues. I am using nibs.

Comment: I am not worrying about if the lines are working, but if they are propperly set to the modalView. I made a test project with the same setup as you explained above, however I can't recreate it. So, some further questions: Is the modal view in a UINavigationController or is the modalview directly opened from the UIViewController? Is the UIViewController an modalview as well?

Comment: @PaulPeelen : No `UIViewController` is not a modalview. It is just a simple ViewController with NavigationBar.

Comment: Ok, by that I understand that the `UIViewController` exists in a `UINavigationController`. I can't recreate the problem using an `UINavigationController` either. I think you have to show more code since you seem to do something that messes up the window view hierarchy.

Comment: @PaulPeelen: I really don't think so. Btw tell me what did you get as a result when you made a test project.

Comment: I got the correct result. The HUD showing in front of all views. I put it quickly together withing a few minutes, so don't look at the code. Here is my source: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cbb8hhvp8kg6ozd/testSVP.zip. Uses the cocoapods lib, so open the workspace file (incase you are not familiar with cocoapods). In this one I change the opening to open from `UINavigationController` but tested even your solution. Try testing opening from nav yourself, and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: @PaulPeelen: Ok. Thanks for the help. Let me re-check all the code line by line from the starting if i missed something.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42041/discussion-between-paul-peelen-and-vin)

Comment: So, did you solve it in the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got to manage the issue using [NSThread](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Actually, I was calling one method named `-postForEditDispatch` from my `-saveButtonTapped` method. I created one separate thread using `-detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject:` and tried to call that method on that thread.

**Sample Code :**

```
- (IBAction)saveButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Modal Save Pressed.");
    [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Loading..."];
    // Some other code...

    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(postForEditDispatch:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}
```

Comment: What we should have inside "postForEditDispatch" function?